# Is there a way to resume YouTube video uploads without losing the order of them?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to resume YouTube video uploads without losing the order of them?

For example this video mentions a way to resume video uploads, where you click cancel, then you reupload. But then I think maybe you'd lose the order

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmUQqoQOAT8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just upload the video again, same filename, and it should recognise that a file was kind of stuck, and resume that. And you retain the order.

Comment: resource monitor may help too to see if it looks like the web browser is sending lots of data out - file transfer happening